# Lookup an internal value on a datatable R

Tags: r, datatable, lookup

I have a datatable with two identifiers and a value like this:

```
dt <- data.table(id=LETTERS[1:8], id_opposite=c("B","A","H","D", "F","C", "E","G"), value = 1:8)
dt
   id id_opposite value
1:  A           B     1
2:  B           A     2
3:  C           H     3
4:  D           D     4
5:  E           F     5
6:  F           C     6
7:  G           E     7
8:  H           G     8
```

I want to add a column containing the value corresponding to id_opposite. So for the first row, that would be 2, and for the second row it would be 1. ie my desired output is this:

```
  id id_opposite value value_opposite
1  A           B     1              2
2  B           A     2              1
3  C           H     3              8
4  D           D     4              4
5  E           F     5              6
6  F           C     6              3
7  G           E     7              5
8  H           G     8              7
```

I know I can do this by constructing a lookup table from dt, and then merging it with dt, but is there a way of doing in datatable, something like

```
dt[, value_opposite := dt[some-function-of-id_opposite-and-value]]
```

Thanks if you have any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple self-join:

```
dt[dt, value_opposite := i.value, on = .(id_opposite = id)]
```

Answer (score 1):

For this particular case:

```
dt$value_opposite <- match(dt$id_opposite, dt$id)
```

But if your values are different than indexes you can aldo do:

```
dt$value_opposite <- dt$value[match(dt$id_opposite, dt$id)]
dt
   id id_opposite value value_opposite
1:  A           B     1              2
2:  B           A     2              1
3:  C           H     3              8
4:  D           D     4              4
5:  E           F     5              6
6:  F           C     6              3
7:  G           E     7              5
8:  H           G     8              7
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use the dplyr package, because I think it uses a more intuitive and readable syntax.

```
library(dplyr)
dt <- data.frame(id=LETTERS[1:8], id_opposite=c("B","A","H","D", "F","C", "E","G"), value = 1:8)

# Simpler solution
dt %>%
  inner_join(dt, by = c("id_opposite" = "id")) %>%
  select(id, id_opposite, value = value.x, opposite_value = value.y) %>%
  print(row.names = F)

# Alternative solution    
dt %>%
  inner_join(select(dt, id, value_opposite=value), by = c("id_opposite" = "id")) %>%
  print(row.names = F)
```

Output

```
 id id_opposite value value_opposite
  A           B     1              2
  B           A     2              1
  C           H     3              8
  D           D     4              4
  E           F     5              6
  F           C     6              3
  G           E     7              5
  H           G     8              7
```